# Detect current Section with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm working on a onePage website. I have a fixed menu in pure HTML, here's the code :

```
<header class="header-menu">
    <div class="header-menu-inside">
        <h1>WM Flying</h1>
        <nav class="menu menustandard">
            <a class="target-section1 current" href="#section1">Home</a>
            <a class="target-section2" href="#section2">About</a>
            <a class="target-section3" href="#section3">Portfolio</a>
            <a class="target-section4" href="#section4">The team</a>
            <a class="target-section5" href="#section5">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="main" id="main">
    <section id="section1" class="home">
    </section>
    <section id="section2" class="about">
    </section>
    <section id="section3" class="portfolio">
    </section>
    <section id="section4" class="team">
    </section>
    <section id="section5" class="contact">
    </section>
</div>
```

Then I would like to change the "current" section to apply a different style to the selected menu. here's my javascript :

```
var currentSection = "section1";

function change($section){
    $('nav.menu a').removeClass('current');
    currentSection = $section.attr('id');
    $('body').removeClass();
    $('body').addClass( $section.attr('id') + '-visible' );
    $('.target-'+currentSection).addClass('current');
}
```

Then I just apply a css like this :

```
nav a.current, nav a:hover{
    background: #F0F0F0;
    color: #E46C51;
}
```

to call the function, I use this :

```
$("#main section").waypoint( function( direction ) {
    if( direction === 'down' ) {
        change( $( this ) );
    }
}, { offset: '20%' } ).waypoint( function( direction ) {
    if( direction === 'up' ) {
        change( $( this ) );
    }
}, { offset: '-20%' } );
```

But it doesn't seems to work. Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much,

Nicolas

Comment: Doesn't work? How so? What does it do? Any errors?

Comment: No it just does nothing... Like if no function were used

Comment: Well, did the function get called? Put a console.log in it.

Comment: Um... how exactly are you calling the function here?

Comment: See edit on main post

Comment: I now have this error : TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#main section").waypoint( function( direction ) {...

Comment: make sure your waypoint library is included http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: In my work I'm required to use YUI so my JQuery is quite rusty, but it seems like 'waypoint' isn't part of JQuery but an add-on, so check if it's included in your code.

Comment: Yes waypoints is well included

Comment: SORRY GUYS!!!!! It was because I included waypoints before jquery...!!! Grrrrr so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    // Select all links with hashes
    $('a[href*="#"]')
      // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
      .not('[href="#"]')
      .not('[href="#0"]')
      .click(function (event) {
          // On-page links
          if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
            &&
            location.hostname == this.hostname
          ) {
              // Figure out element
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
              // Does a target exist?
              if (target.length) {
                  //remove all class 'current-session before add new class'
                  $(".menustandard").children().removeClass("current-session");
                  var id_target = target.attr('id');
                  var current_section_menu = $(".menustandard " + "a[href='#" + id_target + "']");
                  //add css current section selector
                  current_section_menu.addClass('current-session');

                  // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
                  event.preventDefault();
              }
          }
      });
});
```

and CSS is

```
.current-session{
    //your style here
}
```